# Миграция чата на node.js

Tags: node.js

На моем проекте уже существует чат на mootools он проверяет каждые 5 секунд обовления и да сервер сильно нагружается.

Вопрос как обновить мой чат на nodejs? я сколько иследую этот материал все доконца его понять немогу

Comment: Название вопроса должно отражать суть.

Comment: покажите хоть примерно как у вас реализован чат на сервере, тогда можно будет сказать как улучшить

Comment: вы не поверите как все просто, нужно только:

 - поставить node.js
 - переписать логику
 - запустить

*"я сколько иследую этот материал"* - если не секрет сколько-же?

Answer (score 2):

Переползайте на вебсокеты, воспользуйтесь [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). Чатик на вебсокетах делается на раз-два.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказали Выше, рекомендую мигрировать на WebSockets. Будете получать данные в реальном времени с гораздо меньшей нагрузкой на сервер, по сравнению с long-polling.